# Parsing CSV file with Posts.body as a column on Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer, code-formatting

I am trying to run a query which retrieves all questions and their corresponding up/down votes. I also retrieve the title, tags and body.

However, when using a CSV parser, I keep running into problems. Either the parser treats parts of the code in the body as a new line or theres commas in the code. I have used the REPLACE function to replace the commas in title however replacing commas in body with code is not possible.

Can anyone recommend a solution for this? Is it possible to somehow enclose the body within some characters which would keep it all on one line? And then, I can parse the file and count occurences of commas, and once I get to the last one I can just split the string there and retrieve the body.

Alternatively, does anyone know a way in which I can export the data as an XML file? I have tried returning it in XML format, however it cuts off after a certain number of characters. I need 50k results and it just splits the XML in loads of rows in the CSV file. This method is not very efficient therefore I am looking for another solution.

Comment: Even though this is about the data explorer, I wonder if this is not better for the main site, after including a bit more information.

Comment: Ok mate thanks I will post on the main site then

Comment: Do you have a specific query that demonstrates the problem? If there's an issue with the CSV file as-generated, that can be fixed in Data Explorer itself.

Comment: Say you just ran a standard query which gave you Post.id, Post.title, Post.tags, Post.ViewCount, Post.FavoriteCount and Post.body. Also suppose there are no commas in the title.

How would you then parse that in the CSV file? 

The problem at the moment is that sometimes the body goes on multiple lines therefore when using the buffered reader I get line by line which I then parse. However if the body is on multiple lines then a problem occurs. I hope that makes the problem clear.

Answer (score 2):

The problems (at least in Excel) start when a field has linebreaks in it.

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/223179/csv-compliant-excel-export-of-posts) overcomes that by [nesting multiple replace statements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234911/can-we-have-functions-in-sede/234983#234983) which change linebreaks and carrigereturn characters to html markup: `<br />`

```sql
select top 100
       id
     , replace(
         replace(
            replace(
              title,
              char(10) + char(13), '<br />'), 
            char(10) , '<br />'),
         char(13) , '<br />') as [title]
     , tags
     , ViewCount
     , FavoriteCount
     , replace(
         replace(
            replace(
              body,
              char(10) + char(13), '<br />'), 
            char(10) , '<br />'),
         char(13) , '<br />') as [body]
from posts
where body like '%' + char(10) + '%'
or title like '%' + char(10) + '%'
```

The where clause selects posts with fields that exhibit the said behavior. Do notice that the fields are correctly wrapped in `"` and we don't need to compensate for that.

The outcome of this query can be downloaded as CSV and excel can import this (File > Open > Text in the wizard select `,` as the only separator), giving one row for each record.

#### XML Output

To get an xml output you'll need a little bit more work. First generate a [few rows with xml](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/312276). If you save that result as CSV you get something like this, if opened with a texteditor:

[image: xml output by SEDE in CSV format]

As you can see the file as an header and multiple lines that start (and end with a `"` while the double quotes for the attribute values are escaped. Further more is a root element missing.

This needs post-processing to become a valid xml file. Here is the recipe:

1. Replace the first line with `<root>`
2. Remove the double-quote (`"`) at the start and the end of every line
3. Remove every newline character
   you'll end up with one long line
4. Replace every double double-quote (`""`) with a single double-quote (`"`)
5. Add one last new line `</root>`

Your end result will look like this:
[image: XML formatted output]

It is not hard to implement the recipe in a macro of your favorite text-editor or implement in a general purpose programming language.