# Can we have functions in SEDE?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, data-explorer

I want to define a function for use in an SQL query. But:

```
CREATE FUNCTION permission denied in database 'StackExchange.French'.
```

Is there a workaround that would allow me to do what I'm trying to do, which is to apply some transformation to a string that requires looping over the characters?

```
CREATE FUNCTION FancyStringProcessing(@raw NVarChar(42))
RETURNS NVarChar(42)
AS BEGIN
  …
END
GO
SELECT FancyStringProcessing(Field)
FROM A_table
WHERE SomeClause OR Other
```

`CREATE PROCEDURE` is allowed. I don't know how to leverage that. Can someone cure my ignorance of (T)SQL? Or can `CREATE FUNCTION` be enabled?

Comment: They allow us to create stored procedures? I'm oddly surprised by that...

Comment: @StevenV we allow **temporary** stored procedure, e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE #MyProc`, but there is no such equivalent for functions in SQL Server - so we can't really do anything to help here. CTEs, where applicable, are the best bet.

Comment: I have use a local procedure to successfully wrap what was initially a function: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236787/6309. That means there is a workaround which allows to do *precisely* what you are looking for.

Comment: @VonC : The answer has been removed. May you put an update of your link please?

Comment: @user2284570 VonC's query is http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/209443/272830/longest-time-to-accept-answer-for-a-user, and he commented that he “wrapped the aforementioned function in a local procedure, following [this thread], considering http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/5646/temporary-tables-indexes-and-procedures-work.
[That local procedure returns multiple return values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6999656).”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way for us to reasonably allow this. Your question says we allow `CREATE PROCEDURE`, but that needs a little context. We allow you to create ***temporary*** procedures only, e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE #MyProc`. Which doesn't alter the database for anyone else or affect any other queries.

We can't allow mutation of the shared database for hopefully obvious reasons, nor does SQL Server have any support for temporary functions - so there's no real way for us to sanely allow creating functions.

Not for this exact use case (string processing), but for others finding this later: A [Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) may do what you want here.

Answer (score 11):

As you already found out that functions are **NOT** but stored procedures **ARE** possible you can leverage the [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) and [DECLARE CURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) statement to mimic if you call a function on rows from a result-set.

#### Query script

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE #FancyStringProcessing(
     @raw NVarChar(42)
   , @ret NVarChar(42) OUTPUT -- This is key!
)
AS BEGIN
  select @ret = REVERSE(@raw)
END
GO

declare cur_ph cursor for 
           select top 100 
                  comment 
           from    posthistory
           where comment is not null     
declare @cmt nvarchar(42)
declare @cmt_fan nvarchar(42)
create table #MyFancyResult( comment nvarchar(42))

open cur_ph;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ph 
INTO @cmt
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   EXECUTE #FancyStringProcessing  @cmt, @cmt_fan OUT
   
   INSERT INTO #MyFancyResult values (@cmt_fan)

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur_ph 
   INTO @cmt   
END

close cur_ph;

select comment
from #MyFancyResult
```

You can find this working in [Do fancy processing with procedures](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205858/do-fancy-processing-with-procedures)

#### How does this work

- This basic sample has as FancyStringProcessing stored procedure implementing the REVERSE function.  Note that the name starts with a `#` to indicate a local procedure!
- A cursor is created for the first 100 non-null fields of the posthistory table.
- A temporary table is created  (notice the `#`) to hold the processed results.
- After opening the cursor a row is fetched and its result is stored in a variable.
- If the fetch was succesful the value is passed to the processing SP and the result is captured in an OUPUT variable.
- That variable is INSERTed in the temporary table.
- By fetching the next value it is detemined if the loop can be ended.
- After the loop a simple SELECT on the temporary table outputs the results.

---

Here's another example using this technique, by [VonC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/6309/vonc): [longest time to accept answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/209443/272830/longest-time-to-accept-answer-for-a-user). VonC [notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236787):

> - I have used the function defined in "[How to use DATEDIFF to return year, month and day?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734445/6309)"
> - But, since [`CREATE FUNCTION` is not allowed on SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235082/6309), I have wrapped the aforementioned function in a local procedure, following [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene)'s [recipe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234983/6309), considering "[#Temporary tables, indexes and procedures work on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/5646/temporary-tables-indexes-and-procedures-work)".
>   That [local procedure returns multiple return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6999656/6309).